# How to use flock with yaml?

Tags: perl

I would like to use file locking on yaml files, but how do I get a file handle for the yaml file?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use YAML::Syck;
use Fcntl ':flock';

use warnings;

my $cfg = YAML::Syck::LoadFile('t.yaml');

# need a handle

flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "couldn't get lock: $!\n";

$cfg->{a} = 1;

close $fh;
```

**Update**

Based on the answers I have now tried the following, but it always writes an empty invalid yaml file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use YAML::Syck;
use Fcntl ':flock';
use warnings;

open my $fh, ">t.yaml";

my $cfg = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($fh);

flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "couldn't get lock: $!\n";

$cfg->{a} = 1;

my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($cfg);
$yaml::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1;

print $fh $yaml . "---\n";
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that according to its documentation `LoadFile` also accepts filehandle. You can open first, `flock` and pass handle to `LoadFile`.

**Edit:** I would use something like this:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use YAML::Syck;
use Fcntl ':flock', 'SEEK_SET';

open my $fh, '+<', 't.yaml';
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "couldn't get lock: $!\n";

my $cfg = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($fh);

$cfg->{a} = 1;
$cfg->{b} = 2;

my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($cfg);
$YAML::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1;

seek $fh,0, SEEK_SET;   # seek back to the beginning of file
print $fh $yaml;
close $fh;
```

Comment: I have now tried that, and updated the post with the code. For some reason it always write an empty invalid yaml file. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting - you open `$fh` for writing and then try to load/read from it. You probably need mixed access filehandle: `open my $fh, '+<', 'filename'`

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting - I updated my answer per suggestion above.

Comment: Incredible! Thanks a lot. I was under the impression that `SEEK` is used when one wants to change content in a file using an offset? How do I know when to use `SEEK`?

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting - the filehandle is opened in read/write mode, so with `LoadFile` you move file position pointer to the end of file. If you write without the seek, you would append to the end of file. By seeking we moved position back to the beginning of the file, causing it rewrite the contents. For more details look at [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) and [tell](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) functions docs.

Answer (score 2):

[YAML::Syck::LoadFile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML%3a%3aSyck) accepts a filename **or** an IO object: you could use for example [IO::File::flock](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aFile%3a%3aflock).